# Constructing $\mathbb{P^n}$ "bundle" with different $n$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Can we find a complex/smooth manifold and map $f\colon X\to\mathbb{C}^3$ such that it is a $\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^m$ bundle over linear subspace $\mathbb{C}^1$ and $\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^n$ bundle over the $\mathbb{C}^3-\mathbb{C}^1$, with $m\neq n$?

(I tried the following, but I am not sure if the quotient is a manifold:

Consider $Y'=Bl_\mathbb{C^1}\mathbb{C}^n$, denote the exceptional divisor by $E$, we know $E\cong \mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^{n-2}\times\mathbb{C}^1$, we remove a closed subset $F$ in $E$ and leave a $\mathbb{C}^{n-2}\times \mathbb{C}^1$ in the exceptional divisor, denote $Y'-F$ by $Y$. Then consider $Y\times\mathbb{C}^k$, let $\mathbb{C}^*$ acts as scalar on each fiber of $f\colon X=Y\times \mathbb{C}^k\to Y\to\mathbb{C}^n$.)

(I am trying to find examples to see if $R^2f_*(\mathbb{Z}/d$) is a locally constant sheaf?)

Comment: What would be the dimension of your manifold...?

Comment: You could take $X = \operatorname{Bl}_{(0,0)}(\mathbb{C}^2)\times\mathbb{C}$ and $f = (\pi, \operatorname{id})$ where $\pi$ is the blowdown map. The space $X$ is a $\mathbb{CP}^1$-bundle over $\{(0, 0)\}\times\mathbb{C}$, while it is a $\mathbb{CP}^0$-bundle over $\mathbb{C}^3\setminus(\{(0, 0)\}\times\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thanks! It was asked a long time ago and I roughly remember the motivation was to generalized the notion of Brauer-Severi schemes to the case with jumping fiber dimensions, so preferably we want to have positive dimensional fibers. For example, does there exist a threefold over C^2, with exceptional  fiber P^2 and other fibers P^1?